# How To refresh a table in a Ruby on Rails view when there are new record to show automatically

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Well, this is what I am trying to do, I have Rails app that displays a table displaying some information in the database, and I need it to automatically reload the table (if possible in a partial reload, so I don't have to reload the whole page.) When new data is added to the database.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please check the [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). For view make table as a partial page and use it for updating table automatically

Comment: Ajax, you can use jQuery's ajax implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that the table data can reload, you'll have first to notify th client the content has changed, then actually reload the content. To achieve that you'll have to use Javascript/Ajax on the client side :

- add an action to your controller that returns the last updated
  timestamp in JSON
- store the timestamp in a JS variable
- every n seconds call the action so that you can compare the local and remote timestamps
- use Ajax to replace your table partial with the updated one

jQuery ships with Rails and will handle the Ajax part very efficiently. See [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [jQuery.replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) to replace the old content with the new one.

On the controller action that provides the table, use a parameter so that you can disable the layout rendering when called from Ajax. This way the controller will only provide the relevant content (the view containing table).

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it this way:

- Use Javascript's setInterval function along with jQuery's $.get() function to load a page, say /catalog/1/new_items.

`setInterval(function(){

  $.get("/catalog/1/new_items.js", function(data){

    $("new_items").html(data);

  },

  "html")

}, 30000);`

- Create a new_items.js.erb and put it in your app/views/posts folder.

Contents of new_items.js.erb:

```
<%= render partial: 'new_items', object: @catalog.new_items.last, as: :item %>
```

- Create the above partial with whatever you'd like (if you don't need a partial, you can just write the entire contents of the div in the new_posts.js.erb file.)
- Add a latest method to your catalog Controller, that defines `@catalog`, etc. for the `latest.js.erb` to use.
- Add get '/latest' to your routes.rb