# How to preserve input tag values after ajax refreshes table

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby on rails app showing a table that refreshes its content every 15 seconds. I followed the steps this post laid out.

[How To refresh a table in a Ruby on Rails view when there are new record to show automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652567/how-to-refresh-a-table-in-a-ruby-on-rails-view-when-there-are-new-record-to-show)

For each row in my table, I have a few input fields that takes in number values and displays the output of a function of that number. I set this event to onkeyup so it kind of works like an excel spreadsheet.
I don't want the values in these input fields to reset every time the table contents refresh. I wonder if there is some way to save these values after each table refresh or to make my javascript specifically not re-render the input elements.

Here is my partial _match_table.html.erb

```
<% @data.each_with_index do |data, i| %>
    <% data.match_datetime == nil ? past = false : past = data.match_datetime.past? %>
    <tr id="<%= i %>_tr" class="larger_tr <%= 'danger' if past == true %>">
        <td scope="row"><%= i %></td>
        <td><%= data.team1 %></td>
        <td><%= data.team2 %></td>
        <td id="<%= i %>_ah_odds1" rowspan="5"><%= data.ah_odds1 %></td>
        <td rowspan="5"><%= data.ah %></td>
        <td id="<%= i %>_ah_odds2" rowspan="5"><%= data.ah_odds2 %></td>
        <td rowspan="5"><%= data.ou %></td>
        <td id="<%= i %>_ou_odds1" rowspan="5"><%= data.ou_odds1 %></td>
        <td id="<%= i %>_ou_odds2" rowspan="5"><%= data.ou_odds2 %></td>
        <td rowspan="5"><% if data.match_datetime != nil %>
                <%= local_time(data.match_datetime) %><br>
                <% if past %>Match Ended
                <% else %>
                    Time remaining: &nbsp;
                    <% diff = (data.match_datetime - Time.now) %>
                    <% time_left = diff.to_i %>
                    <% if time_left < 3600 %>
                        <%= time_left/60 %> minutes
                    <% elsif time_left < 86400 %>
                        <%= time_left/3600 %> hours
                    <% else %>
                        <%= time_left/86400 %> days
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% if data.match_datetime != nil %>
    <tr class="smaller_tr warning">
        <td>AH returns</td>
        <td><input class="mytext form-control" id="<%= i %>_ah_team1" type="number"></td>
        <td><input class="mytext form-control" id="<%= i %>_ah_team2" type="number"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="smaller_tr">
        <td>amount</td>
        <td><b id="<%= i %>_ah_am1"></b></td>
        <td><b id="<%= i %>_ah_am2"></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="smaller_tr warning">
        <td>OU returns</td>
        <td><input class="mytext form-control" id="<%= i %>_ou_team1" type="number"></td>
        <td><input class="mytext form-control" id="<%= i %>_ou_team2" type="number"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="smaller_tr">
        <td>amount</td>
        <td><b id="<%= i %>_ou_am1"></b></td>
        <td><b id="<%= i %>_ou_am2"></b></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "Yes, there is some way." In fact, there are probably many, many ways. It would be helpful, for instance, to know if you are trying to update values in existing rows, add new rows, both, or something else. Those details (and possibly others) will make all the difference in what a viable solution might be.

Also, there are lots of things to improve with this code...

`data` is plural. `datum` is the singular form of `data`. In any case `data` is not a very descriptive variable name. Why not use something like `matches`?

I would suggest your create a `DatumDecorator` (using `SimpleDelegator`, perhaps) that handles some of the logic you're doing in your `erb`. Something, perhaps, like:

```
#app/decorators/datum_decorator.rb

DatumDecorator < SimpleDelegator

  def past?
    match_datetime.try(:past?)
  end

  def time_remaining
    return "Match Ended" if past?
    time_left = (match_datetime - Time.now).to_i
    return "#{time_left/60} minutes" if time_left < 3600
    return "#{time_left/3600} hours" if time_left < 86400
    "#{time_left/86400} days"
  end

end
```

If `past` has a value of `true`, `false`, or `nil`, you don't do `if past == true`. You just do `if past`

You don't need to do `if data.match_datetime != nil`, you can do `if !data.match_datetime.nil?` or better yet `if data.match_datetime` (`nil` is a falsey value).

```
<% @data.each_with_index do |datum, i| %>
  <% d_datum = DatumDecorator.new(datum) %>
  <% past = d_datum.past? %>
  <tr id="<%= i %>_tr" class="larger_tr <%= 'danger' if past %>">
    <td scope="row"><%= i %></td>
    <td><%= datum.team1 %></td>
    <td><%= datum.team2 %></td>
    <td id="<%= i %>_ah_odds1" rowspan="5"><%= datum.ah_odds1 %></td>
    <td rowspan="5"><%= datum.ah %></td>
    <td id="<%= i %>_ah_odds2" rowspan="5"><%= datum.ah_odds2 %></td>
    <td rowspan="5"><%= datum.ou %></td>
    <td id="<%= i %>_ou_odds1" rowspan="5"><%= datum.ou_odds1 %></td>
    <td id="<%= i %>_ou_odds2" rowspan="5"><%= datum.ou_odds2 %></td>
    <td rowspan="5">
      <% if datum.match_datetime %>
        <%= local_time(data.match_datetime) %><br>
        <%= d_datum.time_remaining %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <% if datum.match_datetime %>
    <tr class="smaller_tr warning">
      <td>AH returns</td>
      <td><input class="mytext form-control" id="<%= i %>_ah_team1" type="number"></td>
      <td><input class="mytext form-control" id="<%= i %>_ah_team2" type="number"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="smaller_tr">
      <td>amount</td>
      <td><b id="<%= i %>_ah_am1"></b></td>
      <td><b id="<%= i %>_ah_am2"></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="smaller_tr warning">
      <td>OU returns</td>
      <td><input class="mytext form-control" id="<%= i %>_ou_team1" type="number"></td>
      <td><input class="mytext form-control" id="<%= i %>_ou_team2" type="number"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="smaller_tr">
      <td>amount</td>
      <td><b id="<%= i %>_ou_am1"></b></td>
      <td><b id="<%= i %>_ou_am2"></b></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```